# Find rows with the same related rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have main table A with related data (attributes) in table B and pivot table C with attributes of rows in table A.

Tables:

```
A:
id | name

B:
id | attr_name | value

C: 
table_a_id | table_b_id
```

Of course any rows in table A can have many of attributes.

My question is:
When I get any row from table A, I need get other rows with exact the same attributes. Is it possible to do it with one query?

For example:

```
A:
id | name
1  | first item
2  | second item
3  | third item
4  | fourth item
5  | fifth item

B:
id | attr_name | value
1  | color     | blue
2  | color     | green
3  | length    | 10
4  | length    | 5


C: 
table_a_id | table_b_id
1          | 1
1          | 3
2          | 1
2          | 4
3          | 3
4          | 1
4          | 3
5          | 1
5          | 3
```

When I get row 1 from table A (row 1 has attributes 1 and 3), I should find only other rows 4,5 (because only 4 and 5 has attributes 1 and 3- exactly the same as row 1).

When I get row 5, I expect to find other rows 1,4 (the same attributes).

So, I need query to find only those rows that have exactly the same attributes as selected row.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. As formatted text, not images.

Comment: added example... maybe now it will be cleaner...

Comment: Great! Add the expected result as well. And show us your current query attempt.

Comment: I describet expected result in text above... My attempt? the problem is  that I have no idea how to achieve it...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by joining the tables on each other based on the foreign keys:

```
SELECT
  A1.*, B1.*
FROM
  A AS A1
  INNER JOIN C as C1
    ON A1.id=C1.table_a_id
  INNER JOIN  B AS B1
    C1.table_b_id=B1.id
```

Comment: Which foreign keys? (Foreign keys are constraints with the purpose to ensure data consistency.)

Comment: How is this relevant to the question?